# How to give option to select Fliter

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

how to Give options to

```
        <column name="status" class="Katalyst\Rfq\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Katalyst\Rfq\Model\Source\Status"/>
                        <filter>select</filter>
                        <dataType>select</dataType>
                        <label translate="true">Status</label>
                    </settings>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">22</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

in magento 2 admin grid.

current output is shown in image[image: current output]

I want to show some options in it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code.

```
<column name="options" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
        <settings>
            <options class="Vendor\Moduel\Model\Source\Status"/>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Status</label>
        </settings>
</column>
```

**Options.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

/**
 * Class Options
 */
class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{

   /**
     * Get options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
           ['label' => 'label' ,'value' => 'value'],
           ['label' => 'label' ,'value' => 'value']
        ];

    }
 }
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: sorry sir i have changed code according to you but it says Element 'settings': This element is not expected. Expected is ( item ).  please check code once i have eddited

Comment: Settings node should be exact child of column node. Please check your code once.

Comment: Please give an upvote as well :)